# Flutter widgets not available in version 2.0

Tags: flutter, button, widget

I am trying to use flutter widgets that were added in version 2.0 such as TextButton or ElevatedButton instead of RaisedButton or FlatButton but flutter does not recognise them.

I ran flutter --version and this was the terminal output:

```
flutter --version
Flutter 2.5.0-5.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 65cf7de5f4 (7 days ago) • 2021-08-11 15:48:01 -0700
Engine • revision fbeb7e22bd
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-377.4.beta)
```

Any idea why I cannot use these widgets?

EDIT:
This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  WelcomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Button'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: RoundedRectangleBorder()),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ElevatedButton is underlined with red and says: Undefined name 'ElevatedButton'

UPDATE:
After running several commands such as flutter upgrade, flutter clean, invalidated caches and restart android studio, flutter pub get, it now shows me that RaisedButton is deprecated however it still does not have the notion of ElevatedButton or other improvements of version 2.0

I discovered that in the pubspec.lock the sdk for flutter is `flutter: ">=1.17.0"`. I would guess this needs to be 2.0.0 at least, but from what I understand this is generated when pub get is run and doing so does not update this version.

Comment: can you run flutter doctor and show the results?

Comment: Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.5.0-5.1.pre, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: There are no issues there then. If you could kindly edit your question and insert the code where you defined the buttons I could see that

Comment: If you have just updated your flutter version try running flutter clean

Comment: 1-Close and open ide 2- Flutter clean 3- Run

Comment: So it somewhat worked... After flutter clean you can do flutter run, and the app will run but everything in the code such as child: or style: is underlined with red as undefined BUT NOT ElevatedButton and the code executes despite all the reported errors. However if I run pub get, child: and such are back to normal but ElevatedButton is once again undefined and the app will not run! 
Another thing to note is that in the case the app runs, I can only do things from the terminal not the upper right buttons (hot reload and run). So I don't know what else I should update or change for it to work.